# angularjs: how to inject HTML code from controller model

Tags: html, angularjs, code-injection

My controller holds a description which is plain HTML code.
I want this to be injected into a given tag so that it is rendered according to the tags it contains.

I tried the following but the HTML is rendered in the attribute whereas I expected to be into the tag itself.

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="{{stage.description}}"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember since when AngularJS does not allow this anymore.

What you need to do is to include the AngularJS Sanitize library.
You can download the sanitize library somewhere here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/

In your module

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ngSanitize'])
```

In your template

```
<div ng-bind-html="stage.description"></div>
```

Comment: ng-bind-html-unsafe was deprecated in v 1.2.0 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-13

Comment: I did include sanitize module and switched to ng-bind-html. Something I don"t get is that stage.description content is causing error as follows: Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'span' is an unexpected token at column 2 of the expression [<span>Coucou <hr/>Coucou</span>] starting at [span>Coucou <hr/>Coucou</span>].

Comment: Ok. I had to get rid of the doubled embracing curly braces.

Comment: you are right @StéphanedeLuca I had a same issue and removing the curly brackets fixed the `$parse:syntax` error. Also I didint need to include the `ngSanitize` module neither in the current Angular 1.3. It worked without it.

Comment: I believe it worked for me without `ngSanitize` because I used `$sce.trustAsHtml`. If I dont use that I believe I have to use `ngSanitize` module for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the curly braces. The curly braces is just the templating tags. You want to bind the actual variable.

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="stage.description"></div>
```